# sdk ios6 libxml2 expected ';'

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, libxml2

After upgrading to the latest xcode sdk ios6 I can't build my project; I have an issue with `libxml` and can't fix it

This code:

```
typedef void (XMLCDECL *warningSAXFunc) (void *ctx,
                const char *msg, ...) LIBXML_ATTR_FORMAT(2,3);
```

Generates:

> Expected ';' after top level declaration

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have added:

```
${SDKROOT}
```

To the 'Header search path', so it is:

```
${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2
```